# I need a regular expression First name must starts with minimum 2 characters

Tags: regex

I need a `regular expression` First name must starts with minimum 2 characters.

I am using following

```
/^[A-Z a-z]{2,25}$/
```

Comment: Why do you think a first name needs to have two characters? Validating names is [one of the most futile endeavors in programming there is](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)...

Answer (score 3):

Your regex appears to allow spaces so I'm not sure if that's valid.

If you want a regex that dictates at least two alpha characters at the start, you can just use:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{2}/
```

This will force the first two characters to be alpha with no restriction whatsoever on the rest of the string. If you want to (as it looks) allow those same character plus spaces for up to *another* 23 characters after that, use:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z ]{0,23}$/
```

Otherwise, if your definition of characters includes a space even for the first two characters, your current regex should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The question is which regexp are you using? I assume POSIX RE.

Your solution is fairly good, but if You check a real name, the space is useless. (Maybe You are check for mind name as well???) And (I suppose) the first character should be a capital letter, rest lower case, isn't it? If so I suggest:

```
/^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{1,24}$/
```

The advantage of using built in character classes, it that it can work in other languages as well.

Example:

```
$ echo -e "Alpha\nalpha\naLpha\nThisisaverylongfirstname\nThisfirstnameismuchlongertobesure"\
|egrep '^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{1,24}$'
Alpha
Thisisaverylongfirstname
```